# How to speed up ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, system

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and my system is too much slow, I want to speed it up. I have tried several apps and methods like jupitar, cleaning tmp file; but still my system is too much slow.

System haveing: 4GB RAM, I3 Intel Processor, 700 GB HDD, 2 GB Graphic Card

What should I do?